# Streaming auc while training

Tags: classification, auc

I am using the [streaming auc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_auc) to evaluate performance of my binary classifier. Not the [regular auc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc) because the validation is performed batch-wise and the streaming auc accumulates all aucs across all batches.

The problem is that I also want to monitor training (check for overfitting, etc.), but it seems to me that the streaming auc for training does not make sense, it just accumulates all the aucs ever seen and seems meaningless. Am I right? Should I just use the regular auc? Thanks!